# Resetting a component when leaving a page

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a page in my react/redux app that has a search field and I can make an ajax request based on input and display the result on the screen. The problem is that whenever I leave the page and return back it preserves the data I fetched. What is a conventional way of resetting a component whenever you leave the page? I should probably do something with `componentWillUnmount` function, but things don't quite work.

Comment: As long as you are not persisting your application state, there is no way, that your browser keeps data from previous visited pages. Are you sure, this is a React thing?

Comment: Show what your do with `componntWillunmount`

Comment: The info I fetched is kept in redux-store. I guess I should just change the store upon leaving the page.

Answer (score 4):

You store the state in a redux store. Thus the behavior - the data is still there in the store when you navigate between pages. It needs to be removed upon navigating away from page. This could be done by dispatching a reset action from the [componentWillUnmount](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillunmount) lifecycle method of the page component.

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to be storing the fetched data in your redux store? If you are looking for the data to be loaded every time you go to the page and reset whenever you leave, just storing the data in component state would probably be a better fit, since it gives you that behavior by default.